# How to deal with an error condition like missing or bad lookup_value with Excel MATCH and INDEX formulas?

Tags: excel, match

I have the following data and I'm feeding the results of a Match formula into an Index formula to find a matching value.

[image]

When a cell has missing data or data that does not lead to a good resulting value, I get a "#N/A" value.

How would I modify the formula `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C7,B:B,0))` to put a string like "NO_DATA" in a cell where such situations happen? {In other words, I'd like to see "NO_DATA" instead of "#N/A"}.

Comment: It is chosen as correct.  This new question is an extension of that answer to address bad and missing lookup_values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap an IFERROR around it

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C7,B:B,0)),"NO_DATA")
```